# Can no longer build to device after switching to Xcode 8 and transitioning to free (non-paid) developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode8, code-signing-certificate

My Apple Developer account lapsed last month and I had a bunch of unexpected expenses and won't be able to renew till next month, and I just switched to Xcode 8, and between those two things, I've lost the ability to build to my own phone.

I was under the impression that a paid account was no longer necessary for *anything* except submitting to the app store, so it shouldn't be my account that causes this, but I suspect that me starting this project with a paid account, and continuing it without one is the culprit. XCode certainly isn't helping either, as you can see in the screencap below.

[Gee thanks, Apple.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u42zy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there are issues with left over cruft in your system. I would remove XCode, hunt down and clear out all references to XCode, Simulators, etc in your ~/Library directories. Look for directories in caches and stuff called com.apple.dt.* and clear those as well.

I would also clear out any provisioning profiles and certificates from your phone. Even better if you can completely reset it.

Hopefully that will kick whatever is hanging around.

Comment: So, I understand how to remove it all from my computer, but how do I remove a provisioning profile from my phone?

Comment: Yeah, completely uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode fixed the issue.